# ¿Por qué no se actualiza el useState en React?

Tags: react-hooks

Tengo una funcion **getOperation()** y adentro de la misma la funcion **getCategories()**.
En **getOperation()** traigo los datos de una operacion y **seteo** a la variable **idCategory** con el id de la categoria de la operacion.
Y en **getCategories()** cuando hago el **foreach** llamo a la variable **idCategory** para hacer la comparacion, pero esta vacia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
const EditOperation = () => {

 const [stateCategories, setStateCategories] = React.useState([]);
 const [idCategory, setIdCategory] = React.useState("");
 const [user, setUser] = React.useState("");
 const [operation, setOperation] = React.useState([]);
 const { id } = useParams();
 const [catName, setCatName] = React.useState("");
 let operationService = new OperationsService();
 let categoryService = new CategoryService();
 
 eact.useEffect(() => {
   console.log("URL id_operation: " + id);
   if(localStorage.getItem("user") !== null) {
     setUser(localStorage.getItem("user"));
   }
   getOperation();
 }, []);
 
 const getOperation = () => {
    const data = operationService.getOperation(id);
    data.then((res) => {
      console.log("OPERATION DATA:");
      console.log(res);
      setOperation(res);
      // seteando la variable idCategory
      setIdCategory(res[0].category);
      getCategories();
    });
  };
  
  const getCategories = () => {
    const data = categoryService.getCategories();
    // aca el idCategory no lo muestra por consola
    console.log("idCategory hook: " + idCategory);
    data.then((res) => {
      let categories = res;
      setStateCategories(categories);

      // aca nunca muestra el mensaje del console.log
      categories.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.id === idCategory) {
          console.log("Nombre de categoria " + item.name);
          setCatName(item.name);
        }
      });

      const result = categories.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.id !== idCategory;
      });
      
      setStateCategories(result);

    });
  };

}
```

**Si hago todo en la funcion getOperations() de esta forma, si funciona:**

```js
 const getOperation = () => {
    const data = operationService.getOperation(id);
    data.then((res) => {
      console.log("OPERATION DATA:");
      console.log(res);
      setOperation(res);
      setIdCategory(res[0].category);
      //getCategories();
      //////////////////////////////////////////////
      const idCat = res[0].category;
      const data = categoryService.getCategories();
      data.then((res) => {
        //console.log(res);
        let categories = res;

        categories.forEach((item) => {
          if (item.id === idCat) {
            console.log("Nombre de categoria: " + item.name);
            setCatName(item.name);
          }
        });
        // returning the objects with the condition
        const result = categories.filter(function (obj) {
          return obj.id !== idCat;
        });
        setStateCategories(result);
        //setLoading(true);
      });
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    });
  };
```

Comment: Podría deberse a qué cuando llamas a getCategories() luego de setIdCaregory aún no se actualiza el valor de idCategory. Intenta    usar a useEffect para llamar a getCategories ()

Comment: Gracias por responder, llamo a getCategories en el useEffect() y tampoco funciona

Comment: Quise decir en otro useEffect, 
React.useEffect(() => {
   if(idCategory !== ' ') {
     getCategories ()
   }
 }, [idCategory]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya te estuvieron diciendo en los comentarios, estás teniendo un problema de sincronización entre el seteado del estado `idCategory` y las llamadas de tus funciones `getOperation()` y `getCategories()`.

La raíz del problema viene de un error muy común al utilizar React que es creer que cuando seteamos un estado, este se actualiza inmediatamente.

Este caso demuestra que efectivamente no es así porque al utilizar el estado `idCategory` en todas tus funciones, este va a tener su valor inicial que le pusiste al inicializarlo con `React.useState("");`, osea un string en blanco.

Por lo tanto, mi recomendación para solucionar este problema es que intentes pasarle el valor de `idCategory` como argumento en la función en donde necesites usarlo.

Por ejemplo podrías tratar de hacer algo como esto:

Dentro de `getOperation()`, en vez de hacer el `setIdCategory(res[0].category);` se lo pasas directamente a la función así: `getCategories(res[0].category);`.

Luego lo recibes como parámetro de esta forma: `const getCategories = (idCategory) => { ...`

Haciendo esos cambios, todo el código se vería así:

```
const EditOperation = () => {

const [stateCategories, setStateCategories] = React.useState([]);
const [idCategory, setIdCategory] = React.useState("");
const [user, setUser] = React.useState("");
const [operation, setOperation] = React.useState([]);
const { id } = useParams();
const [catName, setCatName] = React.useState("");
let operationService = new OperationsService();
let categoryService = new CategoryService();

react.useEffect(() => {
console.log("URL id_operation: " + id);
if(localStorage.getItem("user") !== null) {
    setUser(localStorage.getItem("user"));
}
getOperation();
}, []);

const getOperation = () => {
    const data = operationService.getOperation(id);
    data.then((res) => {
    console.log("OPERATION DATA:");
    console.log(res);
    setOperation(res);
    // no seteamos el estado
    //setIdCategory(res[0].category);
    //le pasamos el res[0].category directamente como argumento a getCategories()
    getCategories(res[0].category);
    });
};

//Lo recibimos como parámetro ↓ acá  
const getCategories = (idCategory) => {
    const data = categoryService.getCategories();
    console.log("idCategory hook: " + idCategory);
    data.then((res) => {
    let categories = res;
    setStateCategories(categories);

    categories.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.id === idCategory) {
        console.log("Nombre de categoria " + item.name);
        setCatName(item.name);
        }
    });

    const result = categories.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.id !== idCategory;
    });
    
    setStateCategories(result);

    });
};

}
```

Comment: Gracias @Desarrollos-web-Urquiza por tu aporte, acabo de subir a la publicación una forma que si me funciona, la cual es hacer toda la lógica en la función getOperations(), lo que pasa es que la idea es tener dos funciones por aparte para que sea mas legible el codigo.

Comment: Ok. Tu solución funciona porque no estás dependiendo del estado desactualizado `idCategory`, si no más bien de `idCat` que ya está dentro de la misma función y sí tiene dentro los datos que necesitas. Si te parece que es necesario que ambas funciones estén separadas podrías intentar  hacer lo que digo en mi respuesta, y si no funciona lo dejas todo en la misma función.

Comment: to solucion me genera una duda, en getOperation() obtengo la respuesta del servicio, sin embargo vos le estas pasando como argumento res[0].category antes de tener la respuesta del servicio.

Comment: Es verdad. Ahí cometí un error. Ahora edito mi respuesta para explicar mejor lo que quise decir.

Comment: tu respuesta editada funciona! gracias por tu aporte!